# fontawesome icon not showing but why?

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

why are my icons not showing ?

its looks like this:

[image: its looks like this:]

I have added this

```
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bfb4213bb3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css" type="text/css" />
      <!-- Load font awesome icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">
```

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the **fontawesome v6** icon classes instead change the version in search to:
[image: screenshot]

the correct one is :

> `<i class="fas fa-star"></i>`

Answer (score 0):

All you need is your kit for FontAwesome:

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bfb4213bb3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can delete the:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">
```

If your kit is set up correctly, you should be able to see the "how to use" page here:
https://fontawesome.com/kits/bfb4213bb3/use